# How to select, focused textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `textarea` and I want when I press `enter`, if the `length` of `textarea` is less than 5 then add a class to it. actually my problem is that class will be added for two `textarea`. How can I add that class, just for one `textarea` that is focused ?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86829ryz/). And here is my codes:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea-1" name="t_comment"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-2" name="t_comment"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.t_border{
    border:2px dashed;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if (e.keyCode===13){
        if($('textarea', this).val().length <= 5 && !event.shiftKey){
            $('textarea').toggleClass("t_border");
            setTimeout( function(){$('textarea').toggleClass("t_border");}, 400);   
            return false;         
        }  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your `$('textarea')` selectors to `$('textarea:focus')` seems to do the trick.

Here is your updated code, I put the textarea into a variable, it's more efficient not to select it over and over again. http://jsfiddle.net/86829ryz/8/

As suggested in the comments I also changed `event.shiftKey` to `e.shiftKey`, as you never put event in your parameters.

I also added a selector to the event so it will only work in textareas. Otherwise `keydown` even when you're not focused on anything fires the event and returns an error in the console. **This actually makes my whole `:focus` solution kind of redundant**, `var textarea = $(this);` would work too because the event fires from the textarea. But at least now you know how to select an element that's focused, which was the original question.

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', 'textarea', function ( e ) {
    if (e.keyCode===13){
        var textarea = $('textarea:focus');
        if(textarea.val().length <= 5 && !e.shiftKey){
            textarea.toggleClass("t_border");
     setTimeout( function(){textarea.toggleClass("t_border");}, 400);   
                 return false;        
        }  
   }

});
```

[About the :focus pseudo-class on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus)

Comment: @JSantosh Strangely enough on Chrome it doesn't return the error. On Firefox it does. Odd. I fixed the code in my answer, I'll fix the fiddle too.

Comment: yes it is not working in chrome.  chrome is setting `event` to the triggered event if it is not defined. may be chrome feature . learned a new thing today

Answer (score 2):

Updated :

I'm not sure why you were using setTimeout but try this :

```
<textarea id="textarea-1" name="t_comment" class="t_border"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-2" name="t_comment" class="t_border"></textarea>

$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if (e.keyCode===13)
    {

        $('textarea:focus').each(function()
        {
            if($(this).val().length <= 5 && !e.shiftKey)
            {
                $(this).toggleClass("t_border");                      
            } 
        });
   }    

});

.t_border{
    border:2px dashed;  
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/86829ryz/6/

Comment: He wasn't complaining that the border doesn't stay, he was complaining it affects both textareas

Comment: And that is why DinoMyte suggests "this" as the selector

Comment: @TalyaS : The logic says if the length of text is less than 5 , then remove dashed border. If one of your textarea has length more than 5 , it would retain the dashed border.

Comment: The OP specifically writes "actually my problem is that class will be added for two textarea. How can I add that class, just for one textarea that is focused ?"

Also, can you provide a reference to the fact toggleClass only works with a class already defined? I'm pretty sure if there's no class defined toggleClass adds it. Edit: actually I justed tested it, here my button has no class and clicking it adds it http://jsfiddle.net/x39zu3nf/

Comment: @DinoMyte as user is saying it should add only for the textarea which is currently focused.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```js
$( document ).on( 'keydown', 'textarea', function ( e ) {
 if (e.keyCode===13){
        if($(this).val().length <= 5 && !e.shiftKey){
        $(this).addClass("t_border"); 
      return false;       
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("t_border");
        } 
   }
});
```

```css
.t_border{
    border:2px dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-1" name="t_comment"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-2" name="t_comment"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code,

You can use jQuery `each` with `.is(":focus")` find more information from here [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
      var that = this;
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        if ($(that).val().length <= 5 && !event.shiftKey) {
          $(that).addClass("t_border");
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(that).removeClass("t_border");
          }, 400);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.t_border {
  border: 2px dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-1" name="t_comment"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-2" name="t_comment"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Issue i found in OP is `!event.shiftKey` . you defined event as `e` in function but using it as `event`**

I don't want to change your logic. this kind of answer is already posted, but OP logic was modified.

JS

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var self = this; // the textarea is used in setTimeout so can't use this keyword in that function. so set it to some var
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    if ($(self).val().length <= 5 && !e.shiftKey) {
      $(self).toggleClass("t_border");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).toggleClass("t_border");
      }, 400);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ro78qqtk/)

**Note:** `textarea` selector will refer all textarea elements in the DOM, so when working with multiple elements that have same selector using `this` keyword will refer to that one particular element only instead of referring all elements.

Update : Chrome doesn't find this `event` error but other browser do. Chrome sets this `event` to the triggered event if it is not defined.